# How to highlight the textfield?

Tags: ios, ios7

How to highlight the textfield and remove the glow after a few seconds if in textfield is nothing written?

```
if (_TextField.text.length == 0) {
    _TextField.layer.borderWidth = 0.5f;
    _TextField.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
    _TextField.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
    _TextField.clipsToBounds = YES;

}
else if (usersHighestLevel == 0 && [_TextField.text isEqualToString:@"2"]){
    usersHighestLevel = 1;
    intForString = intForString + 1;
    [self questions];}
else if (usersHighestLevel == 0 && ![_TextField.text isEqualToString:@"2"]) {
    usersHighestLevel = 1;
    _TextField.text = nil;
    [self questions];
}
else if (usersHighestLevel == 1 && [_TextField.text isEqualToString:@"green"]) {
    usersHighestLevel = 2;
    intForString = intForString + 1;
    [self questions];
}
```

Comment: I added to the question

Comment: In the transition to the next question it is necessary to remove it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

textField.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
textField.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor];
textField.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeZero;
textField.layer.shadowRadius = 10.0f;
textField.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0;
```

if you want to hide border or shadow after few seconds then use this code .. this one is for after 2 seconds change, but you can add seconds as you want.

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0
                             target:self
                           selector:@selector(doSomethingWhenTimeIsUp:)
                           userInfo:nil
                            repeats:NO];
- (void) doSomethingWhenTimeIsUp:(NSTimer*)t {

    // YES! Do something here that you want to hide after few seconds!!
     [textField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone];

}
```

hope this one helps you.....

Comment: How to remove the shadow after a few seconds?

Comment: @Alex check my answer now , i done some additions in it...

Comment: i think this one helps you otherwise tell me if you need more help..

Answer (score 0):

1.Import quartzcore framework

2.Add shadowopacity,shadowColor... Like this,

```
_textField.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0;   
_textField.layer.shadowRadius = 0.0;
_textField.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
_textField.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, -1.0);
```